# Sequelize raw query not returning results

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Am new to sequalize..If some one help me out from the below issue it will be very greatful.

Am writing the below in node.js api and am expecting the results will be send to the caller

```js
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');

const shiftmaster = async () => {
 await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `ams_posting_dets`", { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
}

return shiftmaster;
```

From postman am running this api but it keep on running and never returning the results...What could be wrong..Any help is greatly appriciated

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are defining shiftMaster as a **function** and return this function.
you may write something like this

```
const trigger = async () => {
const { QueryTypes } = require("sequelize");
const shiftmMaster = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM  ams_posting_dets", { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
return shiftmMaster;
};
```

Comment: i tried using the above code snippet..but running through postman not returning any values. in the table i have more than 50 rows fyi

Comment: exports.shiftmasterlist = (req, res) => {
  const trigger = async () => {
        const { QueryTypes } = require("sequelize");
        const shiftmMaster = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM  ams_posting_dets", { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
        return shiftmMaster;
        };
        
}

Comment: you should use res.json() to send your response back, try this

Comment: exports.shiftmasterlist = async (req, res, next) => {
   const { QueryTypes } = require("sequelize");
   const shiftmMaster = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM ams_posting_dets", {
      type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
   });
   return res.json({ data: shiftmMaster });
};

Comment: no luck..still not working...thanks for supporting

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your code (edited it for you in question)

```js
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');

// define function without return - therefore it will never return anything aparat `undefined`
const shiftmaster = async () => {
 // execute database select, but ignore what was returned
 await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `ams_posting_dets`", { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
}

// file is returning something, that should not be done
return shiftmaster;
```

Instead the code could look like that

```js
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');

exports.shiftmaster = async () => {
 return sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `ams_posting_dets`", { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
}
```

PS: You use SEQUELIZE to NOT write direct (and especially very simple sqls). You should define model of the table `ams_posting_dets` and use its methods instead of raw sqls.